# How to change the direction of writing depending of the country?

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, lang

I am working with a major improvement in a website, currently the language is english but I need support for hebrew, I have modify all my text components and forms for this purpose.

At the moment I have added the next line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="de, fr, it, en, he, iw"/>
```

for to support special characters or symbols (right?)

But I have seen the metadata `dir`in the html tag is needed to specify the direction of writing, but I suppose is needed in all the text components.
Question is: how to change the direction of writing in all these form components depending of the country?

Comment: this article may help you http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir

Comment: yeah, I have readen this article, but if I have different languages depending the user, How to modify this feature? only with the tag `dir=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a clean solution for this topic, working with the class or tag name or id you can specify in the css stylesheets the property `direction: rtl | ltr`for example, but if you need more possibilities of customizing inside your website or hybrid app you can try to work with media queries, different stylesheets depending device and so on, you know, the beautiful world of the media queries!